# Nginx, nuxt.js static generated mode and redirection of trailing slashs

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

i currently have a problem configuring my Nginx correctly for nuxt.js generated sites. 
What i want to achieve is the following

```
/magazin -> /magazin/index.html
/magazin/ -> 301 /magazin

/magazin/artikel/titel-goes-here -> /magazin/artikel/titel-goes-here/index.html
/magazin/artikel/titel-goes-here/ -> 301 /magazin/artikel/titel-goes-here
```

currently this is the other way around.

If im correct i shouldn't use a proxy pass to a e.g. pm2 instance with express etc. as it destroys the sense of static site generation.

But how can i get this page structure to work, as i need the same url's as our legacy service for SEO reasons, which used Angular Universal SSR

my current config is:

```
location ^~ /magazin {
   root /path/to/dist;
   index index.html ;
}
```

if i add something like

```
rewrite ^(.+)/+$ $1 permanent;
```

i get an infinite 301 loop

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the built in `index` directive, as it works the other way around (as you have observed).

You can use `try_files` to test for the existence of the `index.html` file. Use a named `location` to process the redirection.

For example:

```
location ^~ /magazin {
    root /path/to/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1 permanent;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.